# How do I easily manage the IP properties of ListSFTP in nifi?

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm new in nifi, sorry if I ask silly things.

My nifi copies files from remote servers to remote servers so processor flow is like this: ListSFTP -> FetchSFTP -> PutSFTP

The problem is I have so many origin servers (more than 100).

Because all flows do the same thing, I think it's very inefficient to make each processor with UI. (drag and drop is so tired!) Although I can copy the processor, but I have to change the properties manually to modify IPs.

Is there any simple way to manage IP used in ListSFTP?